# Access item in JSON array and display objects data

Tags: json, api

I am trying to use weather API and get open data for first object in JSON array.Instead i get all objects.How can i access for example first object in JSON array?Also how to make so the data will show instead of [object, object].
Right now it looks like this:

[image]

It should look more like this:

```
      "name":"msl",
      "levelType":"hmsl",
      "level":0,
      "values":[
        1031
```

Here is my code:
   HTML:

```
     <ion-header>
       <ion-navbar>
         <ion-title>New App</ion-title>
        </ion-navbar>
        </ion-header>

      <ion-content padding class="no-scroll">
      <ion-grid>
      </ion-row>
       <button ion-button (click) = "getData()">Get Data</button>
        <ion-row>{{result.timeSeries}}</ion-row>

   <ion-row>
        <ion-col>
         </ion-grid>
         </ion-content>
```

TS code:

```
import { Component, state } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, AlertController, Platform, Alert} from 'ionic-angular';
import { MapPage } from '../map/map';
import { NewGamePage } from '../new-game/new-game';
import {AchievmentPage} from '../achievment/achievment';
import {DailyRoutesPage}from '../daily-routes/daily-routes';

import { LocalNotifications } from '@ionic-native/local-notifications'
import { PhonegapLocalNotification } from "@ionic-native/phonegap-local-notification";
import { Push, PushObject, PushOptions} from '@ionic-native/push'

import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";


 @Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

      result: any = [];
      data: Observable<any>;


  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public alertCtrl: AlertController, private platform: Platform, private localNotification: LocalNotifications, private notiPhoneGap: PhonegapLocalNotification, public http: HttpClient) {
  }
   getData(){
    var url = `https://opendata-download-metfcst.smhi.se/api/category/pmp3g/version/2/geotype/point/lon/16.158/lat/58.5812/data.json`;  
    this.data = this.http.get(url);
    this.data.subscribe(data=>{
      this.result = data;
    })
  }



}
```

Comment: That's the default string representation of an object: `console.log('' + {})`. You have to explicitly convert the object to the string (format) you want.

Comment: `console.log(JSON.stringify(name_of_object, null, 2))` would be a better choice.

Comment: @SamuelToh's suggestion is the best advise, if you want to dump all the data into a readable JSON format.

Answer (score 0):

You can "stringify" the data using the built-in [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) function. You will need to specify the padding in the third parameter.

Ignore the CORS proxy, I just used it to bypass the same-origin-policy.

```js
var apiUrl = 'https://opendata-download-metfcst.smhi.se/api';
var apiPointUrl = `${apiUrl}/category/pmp3g/version/2/geotype/point`;

// Builds an API url to get a point at a set of coordinates.
function getPointData(longitude, latitude) {
  return `${apiPointUrl}/lon/${longitude}/lat/${latitude}/data.json`;
}

// Wrapping with a CORS proxy so that there is no issue with Same-Origin-Policy
var requestQuery = `https://cors.io/?${getPointData(16.158, 58.5812)}`;

$.getJSON(requestQuery, (result, status, xhr) => {
  // Display the first two hours in the timeSeries.
  console.log(JSON.stringify(result.timeSeries.slice(0, 2), null, 2));
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank u for all answers!  Samuel Toh your advise helped me